# Can one tie their sukkah wall to keep it from collapsing in heavy wind?

Tags: halacha, sukkah

If the sukkah is able to stand on it's own under normal circumstances, can one tie the sukkah wall "down" to a branch for instance, in order to add extra support for heavy wind?

Comment: Why would you think this might be a problem? Are strong walls not encouraged?

Comment: @DoubleAA Not sure as presented, but they’re asking about tying to “a branch”...as in tree branches? Under trees is a potential problem here worth pointing out.

Comment: I've read and heard that the construction of your succah must be such that it can withstand a *ruach matzui* - a "normal" wind, meaning whatever wind strength is most common in your area. Thus, if you live near a windy coast and it is normal to have gale force winds, then you need to construct strong walls to withstand say 40 - 50 mph winds without attaching it to anything. To me, this general rule implies a "no" answer to your question, as this would appear that your succha is unable to withstand the "normal" wind speed. I.e., I don't think you can reinforce it in case of the unusual wind.

Comment: Another problem with attaching might be that it may make it a "permanent structure", halachically, which is not the idea of the succah.

Comment: @DanF It is one of the opinions in the Gemmorah, **but we don't Pasken so**. We Pasken it's OK if the walls are walls are Kevah. Like disassembling one's roof and replacing it with Schach.

Answer (score 5):

Rambam [Hilchot Shofar and Sucah 4.5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Shofar%2C_Sukkah_and_Lulav.4.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> הָעוֹשֶׂה סֻכָּתוֹ בֵּין הָאִילָנוֹת וְהָאִילָנוֹת דְּפָנוֹת לָהּ. אִם הָיוּ חֲזָקִים **אוֹ שֶׁקָּשַׁר אוֹתָם וְחִזֵּק אוֹתָם עַד שֶׁלֹּא תִּהְיֶה הָרוּחַ הַמְּצוּיָה מְנִידָה אוֹתָם תָּמִיד** וּמִלֵּא בֵּין הָאֲמִירִים בְּתֶבֶן וּבְקַשׁ כְּדֵי שֶׁלֹּא תָּנִיד אוֹתָם הָרוּחַ וְקָשַׁר אוֹתָם **הֲרֵי זוֹ כְּשֵׁרָה**.
>
> one who makes a sukkah between trees and the trees are its panels: If they were [already] strong **or he tied them and [thereby] strengthened them so that a common wind would not always move them;** and he filled between the branches with hay and straw so that the wind not move them and he tied them down - **it is fit.**